# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'get_value' in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x

Just learning python now, have very weak programming background.

I keep getting the error: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'get_value' using python 3.8. 
The file is a random file I downloaded from the internet just to learn how to use dataframes and pandas. The object here is to pull a specific value out of the dataframe, so that I can manipulate it later.

```
import pandas as pd

pb_list = [] pb_list =
pd.read_csv(r"PB2010plus.csv") print(pb_list)
print(type(pb_list))

print(pb_list.get_value(1047, 'Winning Numbers'))
```

here's the error line

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "I:/Python/PycharmProjects/Learning Python 1/probabilityfunsheet.py",
>   line 8, in 
>       print(pb_list.get_value(1047, 1))   File "C:\Users\greyb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py",
>   line 5274, in **getattr**
>       return object.**getattribute**(self, name) AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'get_value'

I am using pycharm, and did some searching, came across https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-get_value/ which is where I got the idea as a potential solution for my 'problem'.

Comment: A simple question (if you are still interested in knowing what may have happened), do you have a `BytesIO` instance somewhere in your code ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Starting it with an underscore worked for me

`df._get_value(index,'name')`

Comment: Thanks, It's work but the question still remains why this has happened?

Answer (score 5):

A good habit while reading data frames in Python is setting them as a variable:

```
import pandas as pd

pb_list = pd.read_csv("PB2010plus.csv")
```

Thus, to visualize them you won't need to `print` them, but you will just need to recall the variable `pb_list`.

```
# take a look to the dataframe
pb_list

# check the dataframe's type 
type(pb_list)

# access to 1047 row index inside the Winning Numbers column
pb_list.get_value(1047, 'Winning Numbers')
```

However `get_value` has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use `.at[]` or `.iat[]` accessors instead.

Regarding your question. If you want to store the value that you are searching for in a variable to manipulate it in the future, here's the code:

```
# storing the desired value in target_value
target_value = pb_list.get_value(1047, 'Winning Numbers')
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try using

`df._get_value()`

instead of

`df.get_value()`

Comment: it is very unlikely for functions to start with an underscore.

Comment: @FilippoSebastio it is a very common practice for Python methods to be named with an underscore if they are a "private" function designed predominantly for internal use only.

Answer (score 1):

The `get_values` method for a DataFrame was deprecated. Use `values()` instead. [More info here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.get_values.html#pandas.DataFrame.get_values)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put the result into a list `pd_list = []` This code will give you an empty list and fill out this list with for loop in general. Try to remove that code and see what happens. Hope this helps.